# How does this logic produce high and low pass filters?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals

I was studying for a signals & systems project and I have come across this code on high and low pass filters for an audio signal on the internet. Now I have tested this code and it works but I really don't understand how it is doing the low/high pass action.
The logic is that a sound is read into MATLAB by using the audioread or wavread function and the audio is stored as an nx2 matrix. The n depends on the sampling rate and the 2 columns are due to the 2 sterio channels. 
Now here is the code for the low pass;

```
[hootie,fs]=wavread('hootie.wav'); % loads Hootie
out=hootie;

for n=2:length(hootie)

out(n,1)=.9*out(n-1,1)+hootie(n,1); % left
out(n,2)=.9*out(n-1,2)+hootie(n,2); % right

end
```

And this is for the high pass;

```
out=hootie;

for n=2:length(hootie)

out(n,1)=hootie(n,1)-hootie(n-1,1); % left
out(n,2)=hootie(n,2)-hootie(n-1,2); % right

end
```

I would really like to know how this produces the filtering effect since this is making no sense to me yet it works. Also shouldn't there be any cutoff points in these filters ?

Comment: This question would fit better in [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). Still I do have answers, so please hold for a few minutes.

Comment: The first one is basically a numerical integration, thus giving a low-pass, while the second one a numerical derivative leading to a high-pass. Consider a simple sin-function, e.g. `sin(om*t)`. Integration leads to `1/om*cos(om*t)`. Whit increasing `om`, the signal gets lower (due to `1/om`), thus giving a low-pass. For the derivative, the value is `om*cos(om*t)`, thus increasing with `om` and therefore giving a high-pass.

Comment: @Nemesis Note that the factor `om` may be complex. Also the point of creating a filter is to find a polynom which defines the factor `om` and a phase shift meeting the requirements.

Comment: @Nemesis This might be a dumb question but i tried dry running the code by hand by drawing a small signal and then applying the code and somehow all i saw was that the amplitudes kept getting higher but i failed to see how this does anything to the frequency

Comment: @Hameem Since your last comment appeared after I submitted my answer I assume that you have read it already. That answer helps explain the behavior of the filters. Do understand the text, otherwise I would advice you to comment and ask for clarification. Do you have any experience from digital filters?

Comment: @Nemesis No actually i dont have any experience in that area. We are currently at the end of our signals and systems course and the next will be DSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency response for a filter can be roughly estimated using a [pole-zero plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole%E2%80%93zero_diagram). How this works can be found on the internet, for example in [this link](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Graphical_Amplitude_Response.html). The filter can be for example be a so called **Finite Impulse Response (FIR) filter**, or an **Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) filter**. The FIR-filters properties is determined only from the input signal (no feedback, open loop), while the IIR-filter uses the previous signal output to control the current signal output (feedback loop or closed loop). The general equation can be written like,

```
a_0*y(n)+a_1*y(n-1)+... = b_0*x(n)+ b_1*x(n-1)+...
```

Applying the discrete fourier transform you may define a filter `H(z) = X(z)/Y(Z)` using the fact that it is possible to define a filter `H(z)` so that `Y(Z)=H(Z)*X(Z)`. Note that I skip a lot of steps here to cut down this text to proper length.

The point of the discussion is that these discrete poles can be mapped in a **pole-zero plot**. The pole-zero plot for digital filters plots the poles and zeros in a diagram where the normalized frequencies, relative to the sampling frequencies are illustrated by the unit circle, where `fs/2` is located at 180 degrees( eg. a frequency `fs/8` will be defined as the polar coordinate (r, phi)=(1,pi/4) ). The "zeros" are then the nominator polynom `A(z)` and the poles are defined by the denominator polynom `B(z)`. A frequency close to a zero will have an attenuation at that frequency. A frequency close to a pole will instead have a high amplifictation at that frequency instead. Further, frequencies far from a pole is attenuated and frequencies far from a zero is amplified.

For your highpass filter you have a polynom,

```
y(n)=x(n)-x(n-1),
```

for each channel. This is transformed and it is possble to create a filter,

```
H(z) = 1 - z^(-1)
```

For your lowpass filter the equation instead looks like this,

```
y(n) - y(n-1) = x(n),
```

which becomes the filter

```
H(z) = 1/( 1-0.9*z^(-1) ).
```

Placing these filters in the pole-zero plot you will have the zero in the highpass filter on the positive x-axis. This means that you will have high attenuation for low frequencies and high amplification for high frequencies. The pole in the lowpass filter will also be loccated on the positive x-axis and will thus amplify low frequencies and attenuate high frequencies.

This description is best illustrated with images, which is why I recommend you to follow my links. Good luck and please comment ask if anything is unclear.